# Compiling Statistics::Basic on strawberry failed

Tags: perl

Running a tool, I had to install Perl. Well, I've installed [Strawberry-Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) and some modules fine. But when I make [Statistics::Basic](http://search.cpan.org/~jettero/Statistics-Basic-1.6607/lib/Statistics/Basic.pod), it fails.

The process to make the module:

- `perl Makefile.PL` (OK)
- `dmake test` (FAIL)

> C:\Perl\perl\lib\Basic>dmake test C:\Perl\perl\bin\perl.exe
>   "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib\lib',
>   'blib\arch')" t/*.t t/05_load_them.t ................... # Test 1 got:
>   "Can't locate Number/Format.pm in @INC (you may need to install the
>   Number::Format module ) (@INC contains:
>   C:\Perl\perl\lib\Basic\blib\lib
>   C:\Perl\perl\lib\Basic\blib\arch C:/Perl/perl/site/lib
>   C:/Perl/perl/vendor/lib  C:/Perl/perl/lib .) at
>   C:\Perl\perl\lib\Basic\blib\lib/Statistics/Basic.pm line
>   8.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Perl\pe rl\lib\Basic\blib\lib/Statistics/Basic.pm line 8.\nCompilation
>   failed in require at
>   C:\Perl\perl\lib\Basic\blib\lib/Statistics/Bas
>   ic/_OneVectorBase.pm line 7.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
>   C:\Perl\perl\lib\Basic\blib\lib/Statistics/Basic/_OneVectorBase.pm
>   line 7.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 1) line 2.\nBEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 2.\n" (t/05_load_them.t
>   at li ne 12) t/05_load_them.t ................... 1/12 #   Expected: "" #
>   t/05_load_them.t line 12 is:     ok($@, "");
>
> . . .

I don't know Perl and I have no idea about the problem. How can I install this module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message says

```
you may need to install the Number::Format module
```

So do this first. As there could be more dependencies, it's usually better to use a tool which is automatically resolving all dependencies, e.g. CPAN.pm:

```
cpan Statistics::Basic
```

Comment: ... it makes another error: _Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Number::Format'._

Comment: Looking at http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Number-Format it seems that Number::Format has many test failures on Windows. I did not check how grave the test failures are. If you don't mind, then you can go into interactive mode of CPAN.pm by just typing `cpan` and then do a forced install `force install Number::Format`.

Comment: Possibly related bug reports: https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=79607 https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=71044

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem with the module Statistics::Basic, so tried to install `Number::Format` and again problem `dmake test` failed!

So  I've just tried `make install` command, and then install modules, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am in Windows. It is solved by executing `dmake install` manually.

```
# install will be failed but you can get source downloaded
> cpan install Number::Format
> cd c:\strawberry\cpan\build
# replace [version] and [random string] with what you see in the directory
> cd Number-Format-[version]-[random string]
# ignore `dmake test`
> dmake install
```